# Kendo UI Treeview Checked - Get the text of all checked nodes

Tags: kendo-treeview

How I can get the text of selected items in Kendo UI Treeview Checked?

E.g **alert($(this).data.text);** is not working. I need to send text of all selected nodes to server I want to get this information in an array.

```
$("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item").each(function () {
                   // change whatever you want, for example:
                   **alert($(this).data.text);**
                   $(this).css("color", "green");
               });
```

Thank You.
Hardeep

Comment: This is working alert(this.textContent);

Comment: Following is working. alert(this.textContent);

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var result = new Array();
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

$("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item").each(function () {
    var text = treeview.dataItem($(this)).text; // .id for ID
    result.push(text);
});
```

then send *result* array to the server.